# Why does a Remove feature plugin does not work

Tags: qgis-plugins

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction
from qgis.core import *

# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
from .resources import *
# Import the code for the dialog
from .Remove_Feature_dialog import RemoveFeatureDialog
import os.path


class RemoveFeature:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

def __init__(self, iface):
    """Constructor.

    :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
        which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
        application at run time.
    :type iface: QgsInterface
    """
    # Save reference to the QGIS interface
    self.iface = iface
    # initialize plugin directory
    self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    # initialize locale
    locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
    locale_path = os.path.join(
        self.plugin_dir,
        'i18n',
        'RemoveFeature_{}.qm'.format(locale))

    if os.path.exists(locale_path):
        self.translator = QTranslator()
        self.translator.load(locale_path)

        if qVersion() > '4.3.3':
            QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

    # Declare instance attributes
    self.actions = []
    self.menu = self.tr(u'&Remove Feature')

    # Check if plugin was started the first time in current QGIS session
    # Must be set in initGui() to survive plugin reloads
    self.first_start = None

# noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
def tr(self, message):
    """Get the translation for a string using Qt translation API.

    We implement this ourselves since we do not inherit QObject.

    :param message: String for translation.
    :type message: str, QString

    :returns: Translated version of message.
    :rtype: QString
    """
    # noinspection PyTypeChecker,PyArgumentList,PyCallByClass
    return QCoreApplication.translate('RemoveFeature', message)


def add_action(
    self,
    icon_path,
    text,
    callback,
    enabled_flag=True,
    add_to_menu=True,
    add_to_toolbar=True,
    status_tip=None,
    whats_this=None,
    parent=None):
    """Add a toolbar icon to the toolbar.

    :param icon_path: Path to the icon for this action. Can be a resource
        path (e.g. ':/plugins/foo/bar.png') or a normal file system path.
    :type icon_path: str

    :param text: Text that should be shown in menu items for this action.
    :type text: str

    :param callback: Function to be called when the action is triggered.
    :type callback: function

    :param enabled_flag: A flag indicating if the action should be enabled
        by default. Defaults to True.
    :type enabled_flag: bool

    :param add_to_menu: Flag indicating whether the action should also
        be added to the menu. Defaults to True.
    :type add_to_menu: bool

    :param add_to_toolbar: Flag indicating whether the action should also
        be added to the toolbar. Defaults to True.
    :type add_to_toolbar: bool

    :param status_tip: Optional text to show in a popup when mouse pointer
        hovers over the action.
    :type status_tip: str

    :param parent: Parent widget for the new action. Defaults None.
    :type parent: QWidget

    :param whats_this: Optional text to show in the status bar when the
        mouse pointer hovers over the action.

    :returns: The action that was created. Note that the action is also
        added to self.actions list.
    :rtype: QAction
    """

    icon = QIcon(icon_path)
    action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
    action.triggered.connect(callback)
    action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)

    if status_tip is not None:
        action.setStatusTip(status_tip)

    if whats_this is not None:
        action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)

    if add_to_toolbar:
        # Adds plugin icon to Plugins toolbar
        self.iface.addToolBarIcon(action)

    if add_to_menu:
        self.iface.addPluginToMenu(
            self.menu,
            action)

    self.actions.append(action)

    return action

def initGui(self):
    """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

    icon_path = ':/plugins/Remove_Feature/icon.png'
    self.add_action(
        icon_path,
        text=self.tr(u'Remove Features'),
        callback=self.run,
        parent=self.iface.mainWindow())

    # will be set False in run()
    self.first_start = True


def unload(self):
    """Removes the plugin menu item and icon from QGIS GUI."""
    for action in self.actions:
        self.iface.removePluginMenu(
            self.tr(u'&Remove Feature'),
            action)
        self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)


def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    # this code will populate the combo box with all vector layer
    self.dlg.layerListCombo.clear()
    layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
    layer_list =[]
    for layer in layers:
        layerType = layer.type()
        if layerType == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
            layer_list.append(layer.name())
    self.dlg.layerListCombo.additems(layer_list)


    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()
    # Run the dialog event loop
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    # See if OK was pressed
    if result:
        # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
        # substitute with your code.
        # delete selected feature from layer chosen by user
        selectedLayerIndex = self.dlg.layerListCombo.currentIndex()
        selectedLayer = layers[selectedLayerIndex]
        selFeatures = selectedLayer.selectedFeatures()
        ids = [f.id() for f in selFeatures]
        selectedLayer.startEditing()
        for fid in ids:
            selectedLayer.deleteFeature(fid)
            selectedLayer.commitChanges()

        mc = self.iface.mapCanvas()
        mc.refresh()
```

Comment: On def run (self)It displays that  line 189, in run
              self.dlg.layerListCombo.clear()
             AttributeError: 'RemoveFeature' object has no attribute 'dlg'